# How to access files in folder with same string in file name in python?

Tags: python, pandas, string, loops, filenames

I am trying to use python to look through a directory folder and match up files with the same strings in the file name. Each of the files of interest in this folder is a ".csv" file, containing a single values column, `Value_Blue` for the Blue files and `Value_Red` for the Red files. The files in this folder go: Blue_111.csv, Blue_124.csv, Blue_145.csv, Blue_165.csv, Blue_176.csv... and then: Red_111.csv, Red_124.csv, Red_145.csv, Red_165.csv, Red_176.csv... and so on. The numbers associated with each of these files do not, as shown, go in equal interval order, but that is not relevant here. For most Blue files, there is a matching Red file with the same numbered extension attached to the file name. And so, there are some Blue files that do not have a corresponding Red file.

What I am trying to do is loop through all Blue files in the directory folder, open them as dataframes, and then find the matching Red file, open that file as a dataframe, and then multiply the `Value` columns together from both of those dataframes, and then send that new dataframe to a new .csv with the file name containing the same extension number.

For example, if in the loop it starts with Blue_111.csv, I then want it to find Red_111.csv. I want both of these .csv files to be opened as dataframes, and the `Value` columns multiplied. I then want to send this newly calculated dataframe to a new .csv called `Green_111.csv, and then keep going in the loop onto Blue_124.csv, etc.

Here is pseudocode exemplifying my goal:

```
folder = Path/to/Directory/Folder

for f in folder that is a .csv with "Blue" in filename:
     blue_df = pd.read_csv(f)  
     red = matching Red file
     red_df = pd.read_csv(red)
     green_df = blue_df.join(red_df) 
     green_df = green_df['Value_Blue'] * green_df['Value_Red']
     green_df.to_csv(Path/to/Directory/Folder/Green_*matching_number*.csv)
```

How can I match the files and then create the calculated output file with the same matched extension number in the file name?

Comment: Is the join of red and blue dataframe based on another key column available in the files? Or the multiplication is just based on line number - this will assume that Blue_111.csv and Red_111.csv has the same number of lines.

Comment: Ah yes, assuming that Blue_111.csv and Red_111.csv have the same number of lines. Good point about the key column, yes let's assume that they are joined on a matching key column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `glob.glob()` to match all filenames matching a wildcard pattern. Then you can use `.replace()` to replace `Blue` with `Red` and `Green` to create the other filenames.

```
import glob, os

folder = 'Path/to/Directory/Folder'

for blue in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, "Blue_*.csv")):
    blue_df = pd.read_csv(blue)
    red = blue.replace("Blue_", "Red_")
    green = blue.replace("Blue_", "Green_")
    red_df = pd.read_csv(red)
    green_df = blue_df.join(red_df) 
    green_df = green_df['Value_Blue'] * green_df['Value_Red']
    green_df.to_csv(green)
```

Comment: This looks good, but how do I treat the output green .csv so that its file name has the same numbered extension in its file name as the red and blue .csv files that produced it?

Comment: We're taking the original blue filename, and just replacing `Blue` with `Green`. The number stays the same.